# Error adding object to mutable array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

```
for (NSString *CurrentArtistName in ArtistNamesArray) {
    CurrentArtistName = [CurrentArtistName stringByMatching:regEx capture:1];
    NSLog(CurrentArtistName);
    [ArtistNames addObject: CurrentArtistName];
}
```

why is this closing my app ?

There are no errors in the coding and the NSLog is logging the CurrentArtistName ? i really cannot understand why ?

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Try `    NSLog(@"%@", CurrentArtistName);` instead.

Comment: NSLog is working as i said it is logging the currentartistname its just closing the app when it gets to adding to the array

Comment: Can you post the output from the crash?

Comment: 2010-10-03 17:53:17.423 ___[878:207] Glee

Comment: As you can see it is logging the correct string, but just not adding to the array ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I forgot to initialize the array XD

Noobie mistake but i thought i did